# Iterator equality

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, operator-overloading, containers

I'm creating a container class which implements a double linked list.

```
template <class T>
class dl_list {
public:
    class link {
    public:
        T* data;
        link *prev, *next;
    };
    class iterator {
        link* node;
    public:
        link* get_node() { return node; }
        // ++, --, * operators, etc.
    };
    // other stuff
};
```

Pretty neat, I'm having fun with it. But one problem I'm having is when I define my equality operators for the iterator type, I have to do a template specialization.

```
template <class T>
bool operator==(typename dl_list<T>::iterator& lhv, typename dl_list<T>::iterator rhv) {
    return lhv.get_node() == rhv.get_node();
}
```

will not work, I have to specialize it like so:

```
bool operator==(typename dl_list<int>::iterator& lhv, typename dl_list<int>::iterator rhv) {
    return lhv.get_node() == rhv.get_node();
}
```

for every type I want to use it for, which is annoying for obvious reasons. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a member of the `iterator` class:

```
bool operator==( const interator& other ) const
{
    return node == other.node;
}
```

Comment: will this work the same way as overloading `::operator==`? I don't want to have to call `it1.operator==(it2)` explicitly.

Comment: Yes. Overloaded operator lookup includes member operators.

Comment: Awesome. I just tried it out and it does work implicitly. `it1 == it2` will call `it1.operator==(it2)` behind the scenes. +1 thanks.

Comment: @MichaelDorst: not always - if the left-hand-side argument is implicitly constructible from an iterator, the member above won't do so in order to compare it to a rhs iterator. You might like that or not, but it does mean `a == b` is not always the same as `b == a`.  (That said, it's often good practice to avoid such implicit constructors anyway).

Comment: I'm having a noob moment. What does "implicitly constructible from an iterator" mean?

Comment: It means that as long as you don't mark the ctor of `iterator` as `explicit`, any `node*` could potentially be implicitly create an `iterator` instance in certain contexts. I recommend you mark `iterator`'s ctor as `explicit` to safe yourself some trouble.

Comment: Do you think it would be disadvantageous to allow a `node*` to implicitly create an `iterator` instance? I'm not sure I know what that means, but it doesn't sound bad...

Comment: @DeadMG I'm confused, you knew this was an option, so why did you say "you can't" in your answer?

Comment: @MichaelDorst: I actually mentioned this in my answer. "define it as a member of the iterator class". What I meant was that your function could not be defined, ever, like it was.

Comment: @MichaelDorst: a constructor from `Node*` could be bad - e.g. client code could assume that, and if you wanted to change the iterator to say a pointer to a shared memory segment and an offset therein then client code breaks. Another sample problem: incrementing an iterator might invoke your custom code to find the next element in the list, but incrementing a pointer just adds `sizeof(`pointer-to-type`)` bytes to the pointer, likely bogus, but easy if clients mix ptrs & iterators. The iterator abstraction should be opaque to client code, with compiler enforcing the separation.

Comment: @DeadMG Oh, I see that you did say that. I should have read more closely.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The compiler cannot know that some `T` is a nested type of some other `U`. Consider

```
template<> class dl_list<float> {
public:
    typedef dl_list<int>::iterator iterator;
};
```

You have to take the iterator type directly as the template parameter, or define it as a member of the iterator class, or define the iterator class outside dl_list and simply make a typedef for it inside dl_list.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest cleanest way is to define the operator inside the iterator class:

```
class iterator
{
  public:
    ...
    friend bool operator==(iterator& lhs, iterator& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.get_node() == rhs.get_node();
    }
};
```

(Bit of a code smell here - I'd have expected `get_node()` to have a `const` version, allowing the `operator==` to accept parameters by `const` reference...)

Comment: Actually now that you point it out, I don't think there should be a non-const version of `get_node()`. That would make `node` changeable. I'm not sure if I care or not, but it might not be a good thing.

Comment: No I'm crazy. I really shouldn't talk about programming at 3am.